Group generated by two one-parameter families
For $A$ and $B$ both $n \mathbin{×} n$ complex matrices consider the one-parameter groups $\mathcal{A} = \{e^{t A} \, | \, t ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mathcal{B} = \{e^{t B} \, | \, t ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$. Is the group $G$ generated by $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ a Lie group? In other words, is
$$
\begin{equation}
  \mathfrak{g} = \{X \, | \, ∀ t ∈ \mathbb{R}, e^{t X} ∈ G \}
\end{equation}
$$
a Lie algebra?
I'm aware that if $G$ is arcwise-connected then it is Lie (Yamabe's theorem). $G$ is clearly path-connected: for any element $e^{t_1 A} e^{t_2 B} \dotsb e^{t_{n - 1} A} e^{t_n B} ∈ G$, just compose the paths $1 ↦ e^{t_n} B ↦ e^{t_{n - 1} A} e^{t_n B} ↦ \dotsc$. If there are only finitely many self-intersections in this path, perhaps it would be possible to adjust the path slightly at each of these to avoid them.
On the other hand, it seems that this answer suggests a counterexample: if $G$ is a dense proper subgroup of a compact simple Lie group, it doesn't seem possible for it to be Lie.
Note that the question is about $G = ⟨\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}⟩$, not about its closure.
If there is a counterexample, is $\mathfrak{g}$ as defined above at least a vector space? I suppose not. Is it true that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a vector space if and only if it is a Lie algebra? (Maybe this is suggested by Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff.)
